# Scan doesn't work with logback.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have log working for my `logback-spring.xml` placed under `src/resource/logback-spring.XML`.
I am using Spring Boot, Maven and Intellij.

But when I add scan property, if I change the log level, it is not reflected.
The XML file isn't changed even in target folder under classes Folder.
I have to rebuild the project in order to get the updated log.

What am I missing here?
Is there anyway I can at least bind the external file for logging?

Below is my `logback-spring.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
 </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="package name" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
 <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>       
</logger>
 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Any pointers is helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the source `logback-spring.xml` located in your `src/main/resources` folder. Scan wont apply to this `logback-spring.xml` but instead to the one in your built application. This can be in the `target` directory, or inside the `war` file generated by packaging your application, or if you have configured it to work from an external location.

If you are running it via `mvn spring-boot:run` try locating the file in

```
target\your-app\WEB-INF\classes\
```

there by changing a log level, scan should pick it up and reflect the change in your logging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you did this in IDEA or something like that, because you were changing the "wrong" file, please check out the picture below, you'll get "crazy"!!

[image: IDEA]